# Receiving an 'InvalidPrinterException' - "No Printers are installed." Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing

But I have several printers installed.  I think the code is pretty standard...

```
    Dim printDocument As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument
    Dim pageSetupDialog As New System.Windows.Forms.PageSetupDialog
    pageSetupDialog.Document = printDocument
    pageSetupDialog.ShowDialog()
```

Did I miss something?  I can even enumerate through my printers in code (I've got five of them).  One is set as the system default.  What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try assigning PageSettings and PrinterSettings on your dialog before calling ShowDialog() ?

```
pageSetupDialog .PageSettings = _
    New System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings

pageSetupDialog .PrinterSettings = _
    New System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
```

[Source.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pagesetupdialog.aspx)

**EDIT:** [This page about the exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a92fcw1.aspx) says:

> Make sure a default printer has been
>   installed.

Do you have one installed?

Comment: Thanks for the post; but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Oddly enough, if I inspect the .PageSettings.PrinterSettings I can see my installed printers.  Weird.

Comment: See my edit about possibly needing a default printer installed.